# fetch() API is truncating location of JSON file

Tags: html, node.js, json, fetch

I am trying to use `fetch()` to grab some JSON data to populate the contents of a drop menu in my HTML page, but I'm noticing something strange. Even though I am mapping the `fetch()` via a relative path, like so:

```
  const response = await fetch('./../../../scheduled-job-list.json');
```

Rather than accessing that path, what's actually being accessed is this path:

```
'http://localhost:3001/scheduled-job-list.json'
```

In other words, all of the `/../` folder steps are being ignored, and it's truncating the path as if the file in question were in the same folder as the `index.html` file.

By the way, I also tried this with an absolute path, and the same thing happened - the path was truncated.

Is this the expected behavior for a `fetch()` request? And, if so, why? And, how can I edit this to actually trace back to the folder where my JSON file actually exists?

Comment: How would it be able to navigate higher than the root folder of the web site?

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. So is there a solution here? Or does the file in question need to exist on the same level as the index.html file?

Comment: The file in question needs to be addressable via a URL at the root level of the web site or below. How that maps internally on your web server is between you and your web server. There are ways of mapping physical folders to URLs that do not bear a relationship to their physical relationship on disk.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. Interesting. Do you have a link to where I can learn more about how to do that?

Comment: Not really. It depends on the web server you're using. In IIS, for instance, it's a matter of creating a virtual folder that points to a different physical folder. Other web servers have similar commands.